# setTimeout event on button click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Hey guys I am trying to make it to where when this button is clicked, the setTimeout function will kick off and display a google map in a modal.  Right now, whenever I click the button the modal just gets stuck displaying the loading gif.  Any ideas of how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!  (I have to have the map on a timer when it loads or else it will just load in the top left corner of the modal.)

The button:

```
<p><a id ="hammondButton" data-toggle="modal" href="#HmapModal" class="btn btn-de
fault"><b>View Map &raquo;</b></a></p>
```

The code:

```
<!-- Hammond Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="HmapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="HmapModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Hammond Location</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="loadingGif" style="position: fixed; margin-left: 14%; margin-top: 15%;" ><img src="~/Content/Images/LGIF.gif" /></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                    <div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:578px;">
                        <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:500px;width:578px;"></div>
                        <style>
                            #gmap_canvas img {
                                max-width: none !important;
                                background: none !important;
                            }
                        </style><a class="google-map-code" href="http://www.map-embed.com" id="get-map-data">www.map-embed.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("#hammondButton").button().click(function () {
                            setTimeout(function init_map() {
                                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                                var myOptions = {
                                    zoom: 13,
                                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.4900271, -90.4629746),
                                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                };
                                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
                                marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.4900271, -90.4629746) });
                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() { infowindow.open(map, marker); });
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }, 2500);
                            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
                            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: **settimeout(function(){}, 2500);** remove **init_map**

Comment: put the settimeout function before calling the init map function?  I tried to remove the settimeout completely using the on button click, and it is still stuck at the loading gif.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you haven;t given the google API key.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE"></script>
```

If you want to use `<a>`, in your java script  write the following.

```
$("#hammondButton").button().click(function () {
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

or else,
Just use button instead of `<a>.`

```
<button id="HmapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="HmapModal"></button>
```

Then add click even in java script

```
$("#hammondButton").click(function () {
                            setTimeout(function init_map() {
                                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                                var myOptions = {
                                    zoom: 13,
                                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.4900271, -90.4629746),
                                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                };
                                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
                                marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.4900271, -90.4629746) });
                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() { infowindow.open(map, marker); });
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }, 2500);
                            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
                            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        });
```

Comment: I replaced the <a> with the <button>.  It is still doing the same thing and just staying at the loading gif.  It makes sense that it would work, but it's like it is not catching that the button was clicked.  Could this be because it is changing to a modal and disregarding the background?

Comment: in your script src you haven't added the Google API key. Is it a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

All I can offer right now is some cleaned-up code, not sure how much, if any, further it will get you but here it is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(30.4900271, -90.4629746),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: loc,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: loc
        });

    function init_map() {
        $("#hammondButton").click(function () {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            // is this necessary?
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });

    }

    window.addEventListener("load", init_map);
</script>
```